# SublimeLinter: How to disable linting for a given line?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimelinter

Flake8 has a command `# noqa`, which disables any linting errors for a given line.

How can I do the same in SublimeLinter?

I do not want to disable any linting rules for the whole file, I'd only like to disable for a given line.